Issue installing greenplum backup restore via gppkg
Whilst installing greenplum_backup_restore-1.30.5-gp7-rhel8-x86_64.gppkg, it failed with error:
Detecting network topology:    [X                                                          ] [ERROR]
Error: unable to resolve domain 'sdw001-1:22'
Caused by:
0: unable to resolve domain 'sdw001-1:22'
1: failed to lookup address information: Name does not resolve
Not quite sure why the port number is included. Is there a way of making it not include the ssh port number in the ping test?
sdw001-1 pings fine.
My system config:
PostgreSQL 12.12 (Greenplum Database 7.2.0 build commit:e1b98a3b5ee92c7ed5faf1cd2b356e6c6446539c) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-22), 64-bit
Added sdw001-1:22 go the host file. sdw001-1:22 pings fine but gppkg still fails with the same error
